# Doctrine 2 ManyToMany entity without extra columns

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I think, [Doctrine doesn't fire events when manyToMany relation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629635/doctrine2-manytomany-doesnt-execute-listener-events), so I guess I want to create my own manyToMany entity.

How should my getters and setters in the manyToMany entity look like to act like the Doctrine's default manyToMany relation? I want no BC break.

Comment: why not resolving to a one-to-many / many-to-one relationship instead of implementing your own stuff?